# Return array of integers from cross-platform DLL

Tags: c#, objective-c, pinvoke, marshalling, dllexport

I created a cross-platform DLL in C++ that compiles on both Windows and Mac OSX. On Windows, I have a C# app that calls the DLL using P/Invoke and on Mac OSX, an objective C app calls the DLL. I have simple functions working just fine but I need a new function that returns an array of integers.

The best example I can find is at [Marshal C++ int array to C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776485/marshal-c-int-array-to-c) and I was able to make it work. However, I would like to modify this example to pass the integer array back as a reference argument instead. The size of the array has to be set at runtime.

Here's what I've tried. The pSize is coming back correctly but the list is empty.

In unmanaged c++:

```
bool GetList(__int32* list, __int32* pSize)
{

    // Some dummy data
    vector<int> ret;
    ret.push_back(5);
    ret.push_back(6);

    list = (__int32*)malloc(ret.size());
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < ret.size(); i++)
    {
            list[i] = ret.at(i);
    }
    *pSize = ret.size();

    return true;
}
```

In C#:

```
[DllImport(@"MyDll.dll",
    CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern bool GetList(out IntPtr arrayPtr, out int size);


public static int[] GetList() {
    IntPtr arrayValue = IntPtr.Zero;
    int size = 0;

    bool b = GetFrames(out arrayValue, out size);
    // arrayValue is 0 here

    int[] result = new int[size];

    Marshal.Copy(arrayValue, result, 0, size);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Please post some code snippets that demonstrate what's not working.

Comment: Hi AaronN - I updated original post

Comment: @user979133: your problem is because `list` is basically a local variable rather than a pointer to a variable on the .Net side. You could use a `ref IntPtr`, but I've posted a simpler solution. If you absolutely need to pass `arrayValue` as a reference let me know.

Comment: The objective-c tag seems misleading. Do you mean C++?

Comment: The objective-c tag is because I need to call this C++ DLL from objective-c as well. I think that will be relatively easy though. I'll give it a call now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the definition of `list`, it really needs to be an `__int32**` in order to pass *back* the address of the allocated array. To breeze through the interop difficulties of pointers-to-pointers, how about you instead return the address of `list` or `null` if it fails:

```
__int32* GetList(__int32* pSize)
{
    // Some dummy data
    vector<int> ret;
    ret.push_back(5);
    ret.push_back(6);

    // per @David's catch, you'll need to allocate the right amount
    __int32* list = (__int32*)malloc(ret.size() * sizeof(__int32));
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < ret.size(); i++)
    {
            list[i] = ret.at(i);
    }
    *pSize = ret.size();

    return list;
}

void RemoveList(__int32* list)
{
    free(list);
}
```

With the appropriate modifications to your C#:

```
[DllImport(@"MyDll.dll",
 CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern IntPtr GetList(out int size);

[DllImport(@"MyDll.dll",
 CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern void RemoveList(IntPtr array);

public static int[] GetList()
{
    int[] result = null;
    int size;

    IntPtr arrayValue = IntPtr.Zero;
    try
    {
        arrayValue = GetList(out size);
        if (arrayValue != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            result = new int[size];
            Marshal.Copy(arrayValue, result, 0, size);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        // don't forget to free the list
        RemoveList(arrayValue);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Very nice sixlettervariables. My intention with passing it back as a reference argument is so that it could return an error code, if any. This is simply to be consistent with the signatures of my other functions. If you believe this will cause some major headaches, I could make an exception for this one.

Comment: @simon.d: if you'd like to return an error code, my suggestion would be to either (A) put it in another `out` parameter, or even better (B) have a separate method which determines the size required and have C# allocate the memory prior to calling the method as Ben suggests.

Answer (score 3):

"Caller-allocates" is the only way to make code portable while keeping it maintainable.  Not only does your code not change the caller's pointer, but the C# code has no way to free the memory you allocated (`malloc`-ed memory won't be cleaned up by garbage collection).

If finding the size is quick (doesn't require generating all the output data), just add a second function to return the size.

If you can't get the size until you generate the data, then make one function return the size and a pointer to the content (`int**`, on the C# side it will be `ref IntPtr`).  And a second function that copies that data to the C# array and frees the native buffer.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Ok, clarified that it's the only *maintainable* way to be portable.