# Passing arrays from C# to C++ library and returning an array

Tags: c#, c++, arrays, interop

I am trying to wrap a C++ library for using in a C# WPF project.  As part of that I need to pass and return large arrays from C# to C++ and return a large array back.  Passing the array seems to be achieved like this:

```
namespace CppWrapper {

    public ref class CppWrapperClass
    {
    public:
        void DoStuff(int* pInt, int arraySize);
    private:        
        computingClass* pCC;
    };
}
```

And then called like this:

```
         int noElements = 1000;
         int[] myArray = new int[noElements];

         for (int i = 0; i < noElements; i++)
            myArray[i] = i * 10;

         unsafe
         {
            fixed (int* pmyArray = &myArray[0])
            {

               CppWrapper.CppWrapperClass controlCpp = new CppWrapper.CppWrapperClass();
               controlCpp.DoStuff(pmyArray, noElements);
            }

         }
```

How do I return an array?

Note: I would appreciate any feedback on the best way of achieving this. I am surprised it is not easier to this from C# to C++.  I found it much easier wrapping the library with JNI.

Comment: In general, there are several ways of interfacing C# to C++. With C++/CLI, you can use IJW 'It Just Works' to avoid a lot of boilerplate. Also beware of std library issues, so you do not malloc/new with one version of stdlib and then free/delete with another.

Comment: What kind of library is your C++ code? The question confuses me a little. The first code block looks like a C++ class declaration but the second appears to be the c#. However you wouldn't be able to directly call it like that. Is the C++ code managed C++ or C++/CLI?

Comment: Change it to `void DoStuff(array<int>^ arr);`  Get rid of all that unnecessary C# code, just add a reference to the DLL and call DoStuff() directly.  Simple enough?

Comment: If you can't use CLI because of external dependency, you can still pass arrays around like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17634480/return-c-array-to-c-sharp