# Return C array to VB.NET

Tags: c, arrays, vb.net, dll

I have a general purpose C DLL, with functions to return pointer to a double array.

I have been able to use it in Perl and C# ([Return C++ array to C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17634480/return-c-array-to-c-sharp)) as per my requirement.

How do I use the array (double) being returned by the DLL in VB.NET?

Comment: Are you talking about VB.NET or VB6? Your question is tagged with VB6 but it is more likely you mean VB.NET.

Comment: @DAXaholic - corrected!

Comment: The C# code directly translated to VB.NET should work. If it doesn't, please explain that in the question.

Comment: @Heinzi - Translation using http://converter.telerik.com/ worked! Thank you...

Comment: @Kanchu: You're welcome! I suggest that you [add an answer to your question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), so that others with the same problem can profit from your solution.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Heinzi:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Declare Function functionReturnsArrayPointer Lib "cLibrary.dll" _
        (ByVal argument1 As Double, ByVal argument2 As Integer) As IntPtr

Sub Main()
    Dim arrayWithResult As Double() = New Double(2) {}
    Dim pointerToArray As IntPtr = functionReturnsArrayPointer(12.345, 6)

    Marshal.Copy(pointerToArray, arrayWithResult, 0, 2)
    ' Can also be done as:
    ' Marshal.Copy(functionReturnsArrayPointer(12.345, 6), arrayWithResult, 0, 2)

    ' Do whatever with array
End Sub
```