# Declare function which its return is 2-point from C++ dll in C#?

Tags: c#, c++, dll

I have a function in C++ dll with its return is 2-point, as follows:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

double** _stdcall f(int *n)
    {
        vector<double> t;
        vector<double> X;
        int i=0, j=0;
        do
        {
            t.push_back(3*i-4);
            X.push_back(2*j);

            i++;
            j++;
        }
        while (i<15&&j<90);
        *n=i;

        double** ret = new double*[2];
        for (i=0;i<2;i++)
            ret[i]=new double[*n];
        for (i=0;i<*n;i++)
        {
            ret[0][i]=t[i];
            ret[1][i]=X[i];
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

Now, I declare this function in C# as follows:

```
[DllImport("exDP.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr[2] f(ref int n_);
```

But there is an error for the syntax of this declaration.

I study as topic: [How to get return array from function with global variable from C++ dll in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25322865/how-to-get-return-array-from-function-with-global-variable-from-c-dll-in-c)

How to declare correctly with this function? Thanks.

**Edit:**
I fixed the error above, remove "2" (the size of array IntPtr) and it's:

```
[DllImport("exDP.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr[] f(ref int n_);
```

Now, all of C# code as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace pABC
{
    public partial class frmABC : Form
    {

        [DllImport("exDP.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr[] f(ref int n_);


        public frmABC()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void cmdOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                int n = 0, i;


                IntPtr[] ret = new IntPtr[2];
                ret = f(ref n);

                double[] t = new double[n];
                Marshal.Copy(ret[0], t, 0, n);
                double[] X = new double[n];
                Marshal.Copy(ret[1], X, 0, n);

                MessageBox.Show("X[0]= " + X[0].ToString());
        }

    }
}
```

I compile OK. When I run it, an error occurs at the line:

```
ret = f(ref n);
```

That is: *Cannot marshal 'return value': Invalid managed/unmanaged type combination.*

How to fix it and get the results correctly. Thanks.

Comment: I wouldn't think you would want an IntPtr, since your function returns `double**`. I don't know C#, so I can't really offer advice. That IntPtr looks suspicious, though.

Comment: You've got a major design problem here.  The first problem is that you've got a memory leak.  C# (and .NET) has no way of correctly freeing memory that has been allocated with `new` in C++.  No matter how they tried, the writers of .NET cannot guarantee the same C++ runtime.  If you want to be able to free the memory from .NET, use `CoTaskMemAlloc` instead.  But, you really have a fixed size array, (2,15), so I'd suggest you simply pass in an array that has been allocated by the managed side and avoid the allocation issues

Comment: Thanks. Now I cannot fix the memory leak. I need run well and I will complete it after. What can I do in this case? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do the same, as you did with one-dimension array.

In fact, C pointer (`*`) is just an integer (4-byte in 32-bit OS and 8-byte in 64-bit OS) that is allocated on the stack and points to a memory on a heap that contains your data. C arrays are just sequences of data with elements located in memory one after another. For example, `double*` in your code points to an array of `double`s.

Now, when you create a multidimensional array (your `double**`, for example), you are actually creating an array of pointers to arrays. That means, the pointer `(double*)*` actually points to an array of `double*`s, and each of them points to an array of `double`s.

Well, I guess you already know that :)

Now, regarding interoperation with C#. Your C# code in your case expects a pointer type, that is, `IntPtr`. To correctly interop this code, you should yet again return an `IntPtr` and use `Marshal.Copy` method, as you did before in your previous question.

But now, after the first call of `Marshal.Copy`, you will get an array of pointers - that is, `IntPtr`. For each of these pointers you should call `Marshal.Copy` yet again to get your `double`s array.

The code would look some kind like this:

```
[DllImport("exDP.dll")]
// x and y are the dimensions of the array.
public static extern IntPtr f(ref int x, ref int y);

private void cmdOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int x, y;

    IntPtr ret = f(ref x, ref y);

    IntPtr[] t = new IntPtr[x];
    Marshal.Copy(ret, t, 0, x);
    double[][] X = new double[x][y];
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)         
    {
        Marshal.Copy(t[i], X[i], 0, y);
    }

    //MessageBox.Show("X[0]= " + X[0].ToString());
}
```

If you will ever have a three-dimensional array (`double***`), you will need to have one more loop, and so on.

Now, regarding the memory leak issue. You can create your arrays in C# before passing them to the C++ code, as the others suggested. But you can also free the memory in C++ by simply exporting another function (let's call it `clear`) and passing the original `IntPtr` there:

*C++*:

```
// x is the first dimension of the array
void __stdcall clear(double** arr, int x)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        // free all inner arrays
        delete[] arr[i];
    }
    delete[] arr;
}
```

*C#*:

```
[DllImport("exDP.dll")]
public static extern void clear(IntPtr arr, int x);

private void cmdOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int x, y;
    IntPtr ret = f(ref x, ref y);
    ...
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)         
    {
        Marshal.Copy(t[i], X[i], 0, y);
    }
    clear(ret, x); // <-- this
}
```

The C Runtime [is aware of the amount of memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197675/how-does-delete-know-the-size-of-the-operand-array) it has previously allocated for each of these pointers, so you won't need to worry about the correctness of `delete[]` operation. But you must be sure to call this function right after you have `Marshal.Copy`ied your arrays, because if you will allocate the new arrays by another call to `f()`, this function will free the new ones, and the old ones will stay in memory.

I hope I have cleared some things out so you can now start coding your project :)

Comment: Thanks Alovchin, I have understood about this. Thanks.