# Can't have an array as a return type in C++? Alternatives?

Tags: c#, c++, arrays, optimization, dll

I'm learning C++ and it seems like it is impossible to have an array as a return type. Is this true?

```
int foo(){}
```

works fine but

```
int[] foo(){}
```

does not. What is the commonly accepted work around to this?

I'm currently working on a project that utilizes both C# and C++. I have a C# file that access some DLL code with:

```
[DllImport("Test.dll")]
public static extern byte[,] getBytes(
    [In] string filePath,
    [In] string dataGroup);
```

My header file has:

```
TEST_DLL BYTE[][] getBytes(std::string filePath, std::string dataGroup);
/* This throws an error since I can't use an array as a return type. */
```

and my implementation inside the .cpp file is:

```
TEST_DLL BYTE[][] getBytes(std::string filePath, std::string dataGroup)
{
    printf("getBytes entered."

    /* More code here...*/
}

/* This also throws an error due to the array use. */
```

Basically, I'm trying to return a 2D byte array from my DLL code **without needing to convert anything on the C# side, i.e., all code execution related to getBytes should occur in the C++ code.**

I have a working example of this that does not use an array but rather a void*, which from my understanding is a pointer to the array I'm returning. I then have a C# function that uses an IntPtr and Marshal.Copy to get the byte array. I'm trying to determine the overhead difference between the two methods. I would imagine that it would be much faster to return a 2D byte array directly from the C++ code instead of using the additional C# conversion code (the datasets I'm using are huge - some over 500GB so every little bit of optimization counts).

Basically, how can I retrieve a 2D byte array purely from my C++ code without having to convert it in C#?

Comment: int* foo(){} will work

Comment: In C++, since *you* can't return an array, use `std::vector`.

Comment: That's not going to interop with C# though, I don't think?

Comment: @stackptr That does not.

Comment: @Steve Wouldn't I still need to convert the data in C#?

Comment: @Roka545 int* myArray = foo(); myArray[0] = 1; ...

Comment: Also see [Why declare a struct that only contains an array in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6966570/why-declare-a-struct-that-only-contains-an-array-in-c)

Comment: Also see [Returning arrays from a function in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27410943/returning-arrays-from-a-function-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

You have two separate issues:

1. Returning an array from a C/C++ function (method)
2. Interoperating with C#.

There are a number of solutions to issue #1. Probably the best is to return a vector (if you want to copy the data out) or a reference to a vector (if you have a return value that will stay around "forever"))  You could also pass in a reference to a vector as a parameter and populate the vector in your function.

Issue #2:  A C# array is NOT a native data type in C++, so you will need special purpose code to "marshal" the data into the appropriate C# type.   See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776485/marshal-c-int-array-to-c-sharp) for more details.

Comment: Is there any way to eliminate the need to marshal the data?

Comment: There are certain criteria necessary for something to be a C# array.  If they are not met then it's not a C# array and if you attempt to use it as one really nasty things happen.  There are obviously ways to pass information from C++ to C# that do not involve Marshaling the data into an array.  In fact it looks as if you have discovered one of them: an IntPtr lets C# access C++ style raw data.  No matter what approach you take, however, you will need to write (or use existing) code on one side or the other of the interface to cope with the different memory models used by C++ and C#.

Comment: There may be one way if the size of the array is known. Then you could create it in C# and send it as a parameter to c++. See also [Marshal arrays using pinvoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bd99e6zt.aspx) for different ways to do that.