# Convert float pointer returned by c++ DLL function to float C#

Tags: c#, c++, .net, dll

`extern`

The return is a pointer to the internal array containing results info. It should not be modified results values are output as a float array (mantissa

Comment: what does it mean to convert a pointer to an array of floats to a single float? The first element? The second element?

Comment: @ 463035818_is_not_a_number
The first element pointed by the returned value

Comment: this may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776485/marshal-c-int-array-to-c-sharp

Comment: The pointer should be to a byte array.  So converting from byte array to float is simple :             double num = 123.456;
            byte[] numBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(num);
            double results = BitConverter.ToDouble(numBytes,0);

Comment: Thank very much I solved the problem with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776485/marshal-c-int-array-to-c-sharp

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Marshal C++ int array to C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776485/marshal-c-int-array-to-c-sharp)